# I can't wrap my head around the idea of matter interacting with spacetime. How is the interaction taking place?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, vacuum

I have tried Googling this for a long time. I have read many forums on this. But still, it doesn't make sense.

General relativity says that space-time is bent/changes when a massive object is there. The more massive an object, the more it is bent. And this results in gravity.

My question is, how is the interaction between the massive object and space-time taking place ? We know what matter is made of. What is space-time made of ?

Online research tells me that there is no interaction between the two, and space-time is nothing. That it is an inherent property of space-time to change in the presence of a massive object.

I don't buy that. Imagine a 1000 years ago people came across two rocks, that somehow affected each other. In the presence of the other, they either attracted, or repulsed the other. The explanation that it is just how things are would not have been enough. Of-course now we call it magnetism.

So, there must be some sort of interaction taking place between matter and space-time for it to change its shape. Or respond to it. Space-time must somehow know that matter is there, otherwise it won't respond to it. Perhaps a hidden force that we yet don't know of?

Please help me understand this.

Comment: The [action integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein–Hilbert_action#Derivation_of_Einstein_field_equations) has local “interaction” terms involving the matter 
Lagrangian density and the metric’s $\sqrt{-g}$. This is one coupling. Others appear everywhere that scalar products appear in the matter Langrangian density, since they also involve the metric. There are matter-spacetime couplings galore! No hidden force is necessary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I will not pretend it is easy to understand, or that it gives some "last answers", but the "sort of interaction taking place between matter and space-time" IS what we call gravity, and general relativity describes it. You are certainly aware that charged particles have an electromagnetic field, something electrodynamics describes. Would you also ask "How does the electromagnetic field know that the charge is there? Is there some kind of hidden force?"But there is not another force, the EM field "knows" the charge is there because of the EM interaction.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much an answer (nobody really knows) as a useful mental model, that may help.

One point of view is that matter *is* the curvature of spacetime, in the same way that the ripples on the surface of a pond *are* the curvature of the water surface. This is the idea behind the Kaluza-Klein attempt to unify gravity and electromagnetism, and the Grand Unified Theories (GUTs).

The Kaluza-Klein approach observed that if you extend the equations of general relativity for a *five*-dimensional spacetime, and somehow hid one of the dimensions by making it very small, you got something that looked like Maxwell's equations in curved four-dimensional spacetime. The electromagnetic field is a form of *matter*, that we usually think of as *inhabiting* spacetime. This suggested that if you could extend spacetime geometry to something a bit more complicated, but wrap up most of the details very small, that *all* the matter fields could be explained as different sorts of knots and waves and curvatures of spacetime geometry.

The Einstein field equation sets the Einstein tensor on the left, which is made up of pure geometrical curvature, equal to the energy-momentum-stress tensor on the right, which is the distribution of matter. You can interpret that to define how each *affects* the other, or you can take the equality literally, and suggest that energy, momentum, and stress *are* spacetime curvature. The geometry requires certain aspects of curvature to be locally conserved, so they *act like* a material.

Then each sort of matter is a different mode of oscillation of spacetime, and we can start to see how particles can interact with one another, change identities, seem to pop out of nowhere when you bang two particles into each other very hard, or vanish when a particle oscilating one way runs into an antiparticle oscillating in exactly the reverse way.

Nobody has yet managed to build a fully working theory yet, but there are lots of intriguing patterns and regularities that suggest that something of the sort might be the case. If you take the rotation group for ten-dimensional space, and add a couple of constraints, you get a pattern of potential independent oscillations that matches the quantum numbers of one generation of particles in the Standard Model. (See Baez and Huerta, [The Algebra of Grand Unified Theories](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/guts.pdf).) It's too much to be a coincidence, but we don't have the complete story yet.

In this "matter *is* geometry" viewpoint, there is no need for spacetime and matter to have any special means to interact, because they are the same thing. Matter is spacetime curvature, and the contributions of the long-range part of that curvature add up, to create gravity. The short-range stuff that distinguishes the different sorts of particles mostly cancels out at longer ranges. (Mass, spin, and charge have long-range gravitational effects.) If, as Grand Unified Theories suggest, these are all geometrical properties at the ultra-microscopic level, then the reason for them having long-range effects on spacetime curvature seems likely to be geometrical too.

But not everybody agrees. We have no working GUT. We have no working theory of quantum gravity. It's all speculative, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Space Time is not "made of" anything it is the dimensions in which matter exists. Matter warps space making it a shorter(or farther) "distance" between one point and another.

The main problem with:

> Space-time must somehow know that matter is there, otherwise it won't respond to it. Perhaps a hidden force that we yet don't know of?

Is that gravity used to be thought of as a "force" but now we know it is a warp in space-time. In order for there to be a "force" some form of "medium" for the force to act in, and that "medium" must exist, with its own rules, without another force making it function. That is in essence what space-time is, a "medium" with rules that govern how matter/gravity/etc. works.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: But my question still remains. If you say space-time is a medium between matter and gravity, then how is matter interacting with that medium ?

Comment: It interacts as defined by the rules that govern that medium. Those rules are set and can not be explained as anything but axioms.

Comment: Do we know those rules ? Matter must be doing something to that medium in order to cause a change ? right ?

Comment: The presence of matter is the "change".

Answer (score 0):

I like this question, as a probing investigation into something we take for granted. I don't have the exact physics for it, but you might like my answer.

Spacetime is physical; that's why you're asking how it interacts with matter. So then spacetime must be some kind of 'substance'. Someone has said that spacetime is a matter of dimensions, but that is an idealist view; as a limit of the universe, spacetime is *real*.

Matter curves spacetime, and the Einstein field equations tell us how. But they don't tell us *why*. That is what you're asking. This is where we enter the realms of string theory and so on, that claim there to be an internal structure to matter, which responds to spacetime symmetrically. We don't have a quantum theory of gravity.

On a theoretical whim, we can speculate a little. In general relativity there is the 'Equivalence Principle', which is where one cannot distinguish between a gravitational field and an accelerating frame. In your question there is matter, and in one or more dimensions, relativistically, this matter is *expanding* at whatever rate, relative to every other piece of matter. That is, the curvature of spacetime is caused by matter *displacing* spacetime, so to speak. It's like putting a stone into water; the water is displaced, and the void is 'pushed outwards' in place of the stone.

So "how" spacetime interacts with matter in this scheme is in the way it *envelops* matter, and distributes itself all over the surface of the object - a bit like surface charge in electromagnetism.